# ListView - Loading Images For Non Visible Items (Using Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter, universal-image-loader

In my fragment, I have a ListView of items which contain some text and an image that takes the entire width of the screen. The images are loaded from a URL and I'm using [Android-Universal-Image-Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) for that.

I'm using a custom adapter (`extends BaseAdapter`) and assigning it to the list this way:

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<Offer> offers;
    private Context context;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, List<Offer> offers) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.offers = offers;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return offers.size();
    }
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return offers.get(position);
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final View view;
        if (convertView == null) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.offer_list_view, parent, false);
        } else {
            view = convertView;
        }

        final Offer offer = offers.get(position);           
        ImageView image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.offer_list_item_image);
        MyImageLoader.getInstance(context).displayImage(offer.getImageUrl(), image); //load the image using the universal image loader
        TextView offerTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.offer_list_item_title);         
        offerTitle.setText(offer.getTitle());
        return view;
    }
}
```

Typically ~2.5 items fit to the screen height. When I scroll down the adpater's getView method is called and the next images are loaded. This isn't the nicest user behavior and I want more than 2-3 items to load every time.

For instance, I want that the itmes/images #3 & #4, that aren't visible at the beginning, will be loaded too so that when I scroll to it, they will already be there.

How can I extends the number of calls to getView so that items that aren't currently visible will be populated too?

Comment: As far as I know that's not really possible as the adapter controls that. So if you really want that behavior you should modify the adapter way of creating the items, and because of performance issues I'm not sure you want that.

Answer (score 0):

That is what the adapter does , it loads only the visile items and recycles these views again and again .. the universal image loader has a cache mechanism ,, so one workaround would be if you ,, load all the images in a for loop once after setting the adapter , your problem will be solved ,,,!!!!.. (obviously the images will apear only after they have been fetched ..so it will obviously take as much time it takes to fetch and display those images , but if once they have been from internet , the next time universal image loader loads them from ur local sd card ,,which will happen instantly ,,,,make sure u have permissions to write to sd card while using universal image loader  )

Answer (score 0):

try using memory and/or disk caching, the image will be downloaded only the first time you scroll to a row. this will make scrolling very smooth

```
        DisplayImageOptions displayDefaultOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .cacheInMemory(true).cacheOnDisc(true).considerExifParams(true)                         
                .build();
ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(context)
                .threadPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY - 2).denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory()
                .defaultDisplayImageOptions(displayDefaultOptions)
                .discCacheFileNameGenerator(new Md5FileNameGenerator())             
                .build();
ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
```